# Cannot get coc-java to work offline with gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, vim, neovim, buildship

I am trying to get coc-java to work in an environment where I don't have internet access. I generated my setup with internet access and transferred it to the offline environment, but when I open a java file and do `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput` and choose `coc-java`, I get a stacktrace beginning with `Cannot download published Gradle versions. at org.eclipse.buildship.core.internal.util.gradle.PublishedGradleVersions.downloadVersionInformation(PublishedGradleVersions.java:165)`...`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org`. I have gradle 7.4.2 already installed, and have the following settings in `~/.vim/coc-settings.json`:

```
      "java.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      "java.autobuild.enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      "java.codeGeneration.generateComments": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      "java.implementationsCodeLens.enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      "java.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      "java.completion.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      "java.foldingRange.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      "java.format.comments.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      "java.format.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      "java.format.onType.enabled" : true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      "java.home" : "/usr/java/jdk-11.0.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      "java.import.gradle.enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      "java.import.gradle.offline.enabled": true,
      "java.import.gradle.home": "/home/me/.opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      "java.import.gradle.user.home": "/home/me/.gradle",                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      "java.import.gradle.version": "7.4.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      "java.import.gradle.wrapper.enabled": false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      "java.import.maven.enabled": true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      "java.progressReports.enabled" : false,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      "java.trace.server": "verbose",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      "java.configuration.runtimes": [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          "name": "JavaSE-11",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          "path": "/usr/java/jdk-11.0.2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          "default": true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      ]
```

The coc-java docs says this about `java.import.gradle.home`: Use Gradle from the specified local installation directory or GRADLE_HOME if the Gradle wrapper is missing or disabled and no 'java.import.gradle.version' is specified.

I've tried removing `java.import.gradle.version` as well, but same issue occurs.

Given that the stacktrace mentions eclipse buildship, I've tried Googling how to change eclipse/buildship settings, but haven't been able to find out how to configure offline settings, if that's even possible. Has anyone been able to get coc-java to work offline with gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Place the gradle-bin zip file in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/wrapper/dists/gradle-<some-version>-bin/<some-hash>/`

---

##### Long Version

I finally managed to hack my way around it. Even with the two properties set in `coc-settings.json`:

```
    "java.import.gradle.offline.enabled": true,
    "java.import.gradle.wrapper.enabled": false,
```

... It still seemed to be trying to fetch gradle-7.1.1 from `services.gradle.org`. After taking a look in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME`, I noticed a `wrapper` directory, despite never using gradle-wrapper for anything, so I dug deeper. After a lot of playing around, I managed to get it to work by taking a `gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip` file I already had and placing it in `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-bin/f29rtwfnc96ub43tt7p47zsru/`. I'm not sure the significance of that hash value nor why it would point to version 7.1.1 of gradle, but after putting the zip file there and opening a java file, it proceeded to create the `gradle-7.4.2` folder under that hash folder with everything needed underneath, and coc commands started to work!